# htaccess redirect everything except .htm when it's not in a particular folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Currently I have the below rules in my htaccess file.
All files should redirect except if they have .htm or .html extensions

```
RewriteRule \.(htm|html)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+_./]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Now the problem is that tinyMce also has files with .htm, and in that case, the redirect should take place.

So, I want to prevent redirection on .htm files except when the folderstructure/url **somewhere** contains "tinyMCE" in it...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following. Trying to fix OP's attempt here, please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tinyMCE [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-+_./]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Or try with following rules too, please try to put ONLY one set of rules either above OR these ones at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!tinyMCE)[A-Za-z0-9-+_./]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Hi, appreciate your help... won't this solution redirect all requests except those in the tinyMCE folder? 

while other .htm files, outside the tinyMCE folder, should also be prevented from redirecting

Comment: @Bernard, Your welcome. IMHO Since html files are present already in backend then it will not be catch these rules anyways :) so please try it once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Thank You, it seems to do the job just fine :)